# Load Javascript Files dynamically in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Hi I am converting a 4 page HTML static site to `backbone.js`. One page contains simple HTML but other pages have javascript files like google charts files and jquery ui files and javascript to load, draw charts.

To develop in `backbone.js`, I thought to create a router and load all my html templates with respect to router value. The body section of my index.html files looks like

```
<body>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

And in `app.js` I have router and View like

```
$(function() {


//Router
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    //pages: '',
    routes: {
        ":route": "loadView",
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    },

    loadView: function(route) {
        console.log('called')
        console.log(route);
        var loadPage = new LoadPage();
        loadPage.render(route);
    },
    defaultRoute: function(actions) {

        var loadPage = new LoadPage();
        loadPage.render('index');

    }
});
//pages
var LoadPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',

    render: function(pages) {
        var that = this;
        //Fetching the template contents
        $.get('templates/'+pages+'.html', function(data) {
            template = _.template(data, {}); //Option to pass any dynamic values to template
            that.$el.append(template); //adding the template content to the main template.
        }, 'html');
    }
});

 var myRouter = new MyRouter();
 //start history service
Backbone.history.start();
});
```

It works well if page isn't having any javascript files and code. For example I have a URL `http://site.local/#leaves`
It loads `templates/leaves.html`. All the HTML is successfully loaded. But in `leaves.html` I am having `google charts and jQuery ui calendar` codes and files like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  //blah blah blah
</script>
```

And

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datepicker/moment.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {

              //blah blah
 </script>
```

Now If I load files the way I am doing these javascript files and code isn't run. I am wondering how can I load these javascript files only when they are needed and make them functional properly.

Comment: Load them at start. Keep having them loaded. Don't load them in templates. They will be available whenever you need them. Use `require.js` or `head.js` or any other JS loader to load them efficiently.

Comment: If I will load them in start they will be available in all pages even where are not required.

Comment: Exactly. Why is that a problem? preload libraries, but have page-specific activation code at the bottom of each template, so they'll activate when they're inserted in the document. Which should just be a one-line call to a function you have in your library.

Comment: So, you prefer loading them over and over again whenever the template is loaded rather than just loading it once at the begining?

Comment: @TJ Got the point now. What about the scripting code that is drawing charts. Where should I put it?

Comment: @Awais Well there are some benefits into lazy loading so loading from the start isn't always the best method.  But I would recommend caching them once you loaded it once.  Take a look at `require.js`.  Seems to be the only way to do JS nowadays. =)